# How can I use Capybara to ensure an element is not visible via z-index?

Tags: capybara

I have tried to do:

```
expect(page).to have_css(:div, text: "This is important!", visible: true)
```

Unfortunately the text "This is important!" is not really "visible". It's not a hidden element, but I have something on top of it using `z-index`. Capybara thinks it's visible though.

**What is the best way to ensure something is actually visible, and not covered up using another element with `z-index`?**

**UPDATE**

Instead of using `z-index` for my implementation, I am now using `visibility: visible` and `visibility: hidden`. Then I can use the same Capybara line above and it works as expected. Would still be useful to know if it's possible for others that need to use `z-index` however.

Comment: This should work as long as you're using a driver that processes CSS (most drivers except rack-test) - whaich driver are you using?

Comment: Selenium WebDriver

Comment: Looks like my previous statement was incorrect and that z-index may not be considered for visibility - need to read the webdriver spec some more to confirm.  It is, however, considered for whether or not an element is interactable so you could verify with something like  `expect(find('div',text: "This is important!").click).to raise_error(/Element is not clickable/)` - not the best but it should work.